# Plot average 'y' vs. 'x' (i.e., to plot single point fix 'x' and calculate average 'y') with line thickness proportional to sample size

Tags: matplotlib

I'd like to plot the average of 'y' against 'x' with the line thickness proportional to the sample size. The dataset has multiple y's for each value of x, and it has multiple different values of x. The reason I'd like to make this kind of plot is that I believe there is a linear relationship between average of 'y' and x, but that relationship breaks down when the sample size (i.e., the no of rows used to calculate the average of 'y') gets too small. Does this kind of plot have a name and is it possible to produce it in Matplotlib? Thank you.

Comment: Seems more suited to a scatter plot, you could calculate group size and group mean, then give group size as an argument to marker size (`s`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matplotlib's [`LineCollection`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.LineCollection) is great when you want to add something to a line plot, but the flexibility comes to a cost...

You have `x0`, `y0` and `count`, the abscissae, the mean values and the no. of samples, then you prepare `x1` and `y1` that are one element longer, the first and the last element being the same as in the data arrays and the inner values being the means of two adjacent abscissae and of two adjacent ordinates.

When we have these 4 arrays, we can prepare the segments needed to instantiate a `LineCollection`, note that beforehand I plot the original data with a very faint line, so that the `ax` can deduce its limits, and finally I add the collection to `ax`.

The result looks BAD but it's EXACTLY what you were asking for. Caveat emptor.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection as lc
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(20220929)

x0 = np.linspace(0, 100, 101)
x1 = np.empty(102)
x1[1:-1] = (x0[:-1]+x0[1:])/2
x1[0] = x0[0] ; x1[-1] = x0[-1]

y0 = np.cumsum(np.random.random(150)-0.48)
for _ in range(49) : y0 = (y0[:-1]+y0[1:])/2
y1 = np.empty(102)
y1[1:-1] = (y0[:-1]+y0[1:])/2
y1[0] = y0[0] ; y1[-1] = y0[-1]

count = 1
for _ in range(10) : count += np.random.randint(0,5, 101)
cmin, cmax = min(count), max(count)
dcount = cmax-cmin
ticcmin,  dticc= 0.5, 3
ticc = [ticcmin+dticc*(c-cmin)/dcount for c in count]

segments = [((x1[i],y1[i]),(x0[i],y0[i]),(x1[i+1],y1[i+1])) for i in range(101)]
lines = lc(segments, linewidths=ticc)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x0, y0, lw=0.01)
ax.add_collection(lines)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you. That's perfect. The magnitudes of the differences in sample sizes are more like "count = np.arange(10001, 0, -100)" in my sample and if I make this change and also the change "ticcmin,  dticc= 0.5, 10" in your code, I get exactly the kind of plot I'm after.

Comment: @gillenpj Happy that I nailed it! and thank you the recognition you gave me